# How is DC bias offset removed in a differential amplifier circuit?

Tags: differential-amplifier, biasing, dc-offset

Looking at the long-tailed pair, if we remove the dual supply and bias the amplifier for single supply operation it will generate a DC-shifted signal. How is this DC-offset typically cancelled for single supply operations where the output must be DC coupled?

Since this design must be DC coupled we cannot use a simple capacitor on the output so this has made me wonder how do they do this in the industry such as in an operational amplifier.

Initially I was thinking a rail splitter "virtual ground" but I do not see any such devices in the circuit, at least the types that I am familiar with. I assume this solution is some multi-stage architecture of sorts?

### Long Tailed Pair (Differential Amplifier)

[image: Long Tailed Pair]

### Circuit Schematic

[image: Circuit Schematic]

### Simulation Results

[image: Simulation Result]

You can see that the output is indeed differential with the output signals being 180° out of phase, but you can see it is offset by approximate 2x V3 voltage of 3.5v.

Comment: SubZero, study this [behavioral OP37 schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH9VU.png). It has a lot of similarity on the first stage as compared to your first diagram and it uses both outputs to feed towards a middle stage before heading on out to the single-ended output on the right. Worth a moment or two. If you power your long tailed pair from a single rail then you are responsible for (roughly) midpoint biasing of your inputs (and your use of NFB, as always.)

Comment: The easy way is to define "0V" out to be VCC/2. Or, define Vout = VC(Q1) - VC (Q2). Otherwise your constraints ... single supply, DC coupling ... mean you can only output half of an AC waveform.

Answer (score 2):

A DC-coupled signal must always stay between the power rails, no matter what you call them...which leads to an important point:

**Named nodes don't really matter as much as most beginners seem to get stuck on.**  I can call anything I want "ground" or 0V, or V+, or V-, or whatever, as long as I only choose *one* arbitrarily.  I'm free to do that, and then run the analysis from there.  The names are only for communication with other humans; they mean absolutely nothing for the circuit itself.

Ever notice that "split supply" opamps still only have the two power pins?

Answer (score 0):

The long-tailed pair is only the front end of an op-amp. The output *is* the difference between the OUT+ and OUT-. Therefore the common mode of these two signals is irrelevant. It carries no information.

An op-amp follows the differential pair with gain stages, often single-ended gain stages and in that case what happens is one of the outputs of the long-tailed pair ignored and not passed onto the next gain stage. Most op-amps are single-ended output so this is all that happens.

For complimentary output amps, the two outputs of the long-tailed pair are both passed onto the next gain stage...either that or they just used a bunch of single-ended gain stages like described previously but the signal is put through another long-tailed pair at the very end to produce the final differential output. And being a differential pair, the information in the output is the difference between the two outputs, and you can fix one of these outputs if you want, but common mode of the two output signals carries no information.

My working knowledge of op-amp internal circuitry is weak so don't try and scrutinize every little detail of what I say, but take it as a broad stroke in a general sense for the basic idea.

Comment: For most of what I've seen, the common mode out of an LTP is fixed (constant total current, steered one way or the other), so you can simply choose one or the other output as "single-ended" depending on the polarity that you need, and ignore the other one.

Comment: @AaronD Does the edit sound right?

Comment: As a broad stroke, it's pretty good.  You've got the basic idea.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

> so this has made me wonder how do they do this in the industry such as in an operational amplifier?

They don't. Inputs require a midpoint bias. Outputs require a midpoint symmetry. 0V is arbitrary.